# Drag the view by touching below the object and move accordingly

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have created an simple drag drop application in android.But now i want to move the view on x-axis without touching the view itself.the View should move from anywhere on the screen where user touched the screen.How can I achieve this effect.

Currently i am using [this](http://www.singhajit.com/android-draggable-view/) tutorial for drag drop operations.I have applied the OnTouchListner on parent view.But i think this is not the good idea.Please can anyone suggest me the correct way of doing it.

Here is my code

```
 rel.setOnTouchListener(this);

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                v.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
                v.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and my xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ball"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ball" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you remove `v.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);` line from `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:` ?

Comment: @MayurRaval yes and it will now move only in x axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this problem is resolved by making some changes in my code.Hope this will help someone achieving this effect.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            dx = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dy = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
            ball_dx = ball.getX();
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //  ball.setY(event.getRawY() + dy);
            if ((event.getRawX() + dx + ball_dx) < screenwidth - 80 && (event.getRawX() + dx + ball_dx) > 10)
                ball.setX(event.getRawX() + dx + ball_dx);
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented , I am writing that as answer May be it help someone.This code will move view on X axis only

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            dX = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           //remove this v.setY() line
            v.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
            lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```